# pytorch regression model showed its learning, but when test the trained model, output is always the same

Tags: parameters, pytorch, regression

I practice to make the regression model using two inputs.
One input is larger vector input in respect to dimension.
So I utilize the Convolutional layer to extract the features.
The codes of model are

```
class CNN_2_practice_model(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(CNN_2_practice_model, self).__init__()
        
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv1d(in_channels=1024, out_channels=1024, kernel_size=2)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv1d(in_channels=1024, out_channels=1024, kernel_size=2)
        self.conv3 = nn.Conv1d(in_channels=1024, out_channels=1024, kernel_size=2)
        
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(in_features=2048, out_features=512)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(in_features=512, out_features=64)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(in_features=64, out_features=1)
    
    def forward(self, x1, x2):
        x1 = self.conv1(x1)
        x1 = nn.ReLU()(x1)
        x1 = nn.MaxPool1d(kernel_size=2)(x1)
        
        x1 = self.conv2(x1)
        x1 = nn.ReLU()(x1)
        x1 = nn.MaxPool1d(kernel_size=2)(x1)
        
        x1 = self.conv3(x1)
        x1 = nn.ReLU()(x1)
        x1 = nn.MaxPool1d(kernel_size=2)(x1)
     
        x1 = torch.flatten(x1, start_dim=1)

        x = torch.cat([x1, x2], dim=0)
        x = x.view( len(x1), -1 )
        x = self.fc1(x)
        x = nn.ReLU()(x)
        x = nn.Dropout(p=0.5)(x)
        x = self.fc2(x)
        x = nn.ReLU()(x)
        x = nn.Dropout(p=0.5)(x)
        x = self.fc3(x)
        x = x.squeeze()
        return x
```

The code of training is below

```
model = CNN_2_practice_model()
criterion = nn.MSELoss()
optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.001)

device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')
print(device)
model.to(device)

train_losses = []
val_losses = []

for epoch in range(1000):
    train_loss = train(model, train_loader, optimizer, criterion)
    val_loss = validate(model, val_loader, criterion)
    train_losses.append(train_loss)
    val_losses.append(val_loss)
    
    print(f'Epoch {epoch+1}, Train Loss: {train_loss_2:.4f}, Val Loss: {val_loss_2:.4f}')
```

The results were
`Epoch 1, Train Loss: 7.3641, Val Loss: 6.1839 Epoch 2, Train Loss: 6.6757, Val Loss: 6.4387 Epoch 3, Train Loss: 6.5833, Val Loss: 6.4213 Epoch 4, Train Loss: 6.2662, Val Loss: 6.4523 Epoch 5, Train Loss: 6.2003, Val Loss: 5.9351 Epoch 6, Train Loss: 6.2768, Val Loss: 6.4744 Epoch 7, Train Loss: 6.3507, Val Loss: 6.3500 Epoch 8, Train Loss: 6.3950, Val Loss: 6.2717 Epoch 9, Train Loss: 5.9085, Val Loss: 5.9503 Epoch 10, Train Loss: 5.8763, Val Loss: 6.2940 Epoch 11, Train Loss: 5.7292, Val Loss: 6.4000 Epoch 12, Train Loss: 6.1611, Val Loss: 5.9204 Epoch 13, Train Loss: 5.7882, Val Loss: 6.2586 Epoch 14, Train Loss: 6.3946, Val Loss: 5.9362 Epoch 15, Train Loss: 6.1327, Val Loss: 6.3741 Epoch 16, Train Loss: 5.9214, Val Loss: 5.5680 Epoch 17, Train Loss: 5.9613, Val Loss: 5.9703 Epoch 18, Train Loss: 5.7861, Val Loss: 5.5218 Epoch 19, Train Loss: 5.7532, Val Loss: 5.4612 Epoch 20, Train Loss: 5.8741, Val Loss: 5.5243 Epoch 21, Train Loss: 5.8041, Val Loss: 5.8064 Epoch 22, Train Loss: 5.6120, Val Loss: 5.8755 Epoch 23, Train Loss: 5.8966, Val Loss: 5.2449 Epoch 24, Train Loss: 5.5326, Val Loss: 5.5123 Epoch 25, Train Loss: 5.7095, Val Loss: 5.2943 ...`

However, the results of test are always the same output value regardless of inputs

```
y_pred = []
y_true = []
with torch.no_grad():
    for batch_idx, (x1, x2, y) in enumerate(test_loader):
        x1 = x1.to(device)
        x2 = x2.to(device)
        y = y.to(device)
        output = model(x1, x2)
        print(y)
        print(output)
```

What is the cause of the situation...?

clear up the problem of codes and expect to have better understaning of machine learning codes

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO. It appears that your validation loss didn't decrease very much from its initial value (unless the part beyond the "..." is much different). Or maybe your model is just overfitting?

A few tips to get your model to run a little bit better:

- According to [Deep Learning with Pytorch](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1617295264), it's better to have kernel sizes that are odd numbers so that you have a definite center. Also, your kernels are a little bit small, and I suspect it may be hard to extract useful features from a 2x2 grid. I would recommend increasing your kernel sizes to 3x3.
- [BCELoss](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.BCELoss.html), or *Binary Cross Entropy*, works better for binary classification tasks, which is what your network appears to be doing, given the fact that it has one output and you're using an architecture commonly used for image classification.
- Change your learning algorithm to SGD and use a learning scheduler. In my experience, sometimes Adam works really well, sometimes it works really poorly, so it's worth experimenting a little bit with this. I recommend [ReduceLROnPlateau](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.optim.lr_scheduler.ReduceLROnPlateau.html).

One last thing, this might be a little bit difficult to do for many types of machine learning problems, but providing a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) goes a long way on Stack Overflow in solving problems.
Good luck!